# py2exe 64 bit python 2.7 installation

Tags: python, python-2.7, executable, py2exe

Is there a pip install for py2exe 64 bit that is for the 64 bit python 2.7? The 32 bit py2exe doesn't work for me, but I keep getting exceptions when I try to install the 64 bit version. I downloaded the 64 bit py2exe for python 2.7 from this site: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#py2exe but can't install it

**The error I am getting using python -m pip install py2exe:**

```
Runtime Error: This package requires Python 3.3 or later
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1
```

**Note: The following works for the 32 bit but I need the 64 bit**

```
pip install http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/latest/download?source=files
```

I am running 64 bit python 2.7 and am trying to install 64 bit py2exe

Any easy pip install for it?

Comment: What errors do you get? Also, does `python -m pip install py2exe` produce the same errors?

Comment: Yes, I keep getting "Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 even when I try what you suggested

Comment: okay. Can you [edit] your question to include a bit more of your traceback?

Comment: Are you using the 32- or 64-bit version of Python? You should use the a version of py2exe that corresponds to that (not the bitness of your OS).

Comment: I'm using the 64 bit python that's why I need the 64 bit py2exe, but it wouldn't install

Comment: @NightShadeQueen done. If I do pip install://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/latest/download?source=files it works but it is the 32 bit py2exe and I need the 64 bit py2exe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found an easy way to install py2exe 64 Bits in Windows 7 or greater.

1. Go to [Official Download Webpage](http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/py2exe/0.6.9/)
2. Download your version: py2exe-0.6.9.win64-**py2.7**.amd64.exe (There are other versions: py2exe-0.6.9.win64-**py2.5**.amd64.msi and py2exe-0.6.9.win64-**py2.6**.amd64.exe)
3. Run the installation
4. And enjoy!

Hope this help you like did to me.

Comment: I installed like you but when I run the python setup.py py2exe appears an error It says invalid command py2exe